# find all possible sums of a list without target

Tags: java

im trying to find all possible sums from a list.
The list consist of ints that are user inputed, and the number of inputs are decided by the user aswell( see code).
What i want is to check all possible sums without having a target. 
The reason i dont want a target is because the program is then later suposed to chose one of these sums which is closest to 1000.
So if i was to pick 1000 as target i wouldnt be able to get say 1001.

Example input from user:

```
5 // user chose 5 numbers.

500,400,300,50,60  // numbers chosen by user.
```

Output would then be:

```
1010 // because 500+400+60+50= 1010 and closest to 1000.
```

Next example could be:

```
3 // user chose 3 numbers.

1,2,3 // numbers chosen by user.
```

Output would then be:

```
6 // because 1+2+3 = 6.
```

So back to my original question, how do is this done? Everytime i search "all possible sums of a list of ints" or simular i get with a target and it dosent work in this example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int bästaVikt;
    int räknare = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int s;
    s = sc.nextInt();
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
        mylist.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {   
        Collections.sort(mylist);
        System.out.print(mylist.get(i));
        System.out.print(" ");  
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1. it was i who closed it and i did it this morning since i had kinda written poorly and explained bad so chose to remake it.
2. its not a homework, im a teamleader with a new assignment, and i've never worked with developers before so im trying to learn basics so i know what they are doing. 
The task can be found online and will prob be one of the first if you google, online assignment java.

Comment: Ok I'm retracting my close vote in this case. Do not take this badly, homework assignments are posted here daily.

Comment: thx i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Half actual code half pseudo code, hope it helps.

```
input // the array that holds all numbers than the user input
int n = input.length();
ArrayList<Integer> combinations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int totalSum = input.sum(); // sum of all the values the user input
ArrayList<Integer> allSums = new ArrayList<Ingeter>();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    combinations = combine(i) // find all possible combinations of i integers in the input array; you can surely find code for retrieving combinations in another thread
    foreach combination in combinations{
        allSums.add(totalSum - combination.sum())
    }
    combinations = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // clear the combinations arraylist
}
return allSums; //all possible sums


minDistanceToNumber = absolute(allSums.get(0) - 1000); // define a function "int absolute(int value)" which will multiply value by -1 if it is less than 0 and return it or just return it if it is bigger than 0
minNumber = allSums.get(0); // this will hold the number which has the minimum distance to 1000, as in the example above
for each sum in allSums
    if(absolute(sum - 1000) < minDistanceToNumber){
        minDistanceToNumber = absolute(sum - 1000);
        minNumber = sum;
    }
}
return minNumber;
```

Comment: thx alot! im gonna have to rework the code abit since, the list with the scanned numbers is a arraylist the 
int n = input.length(); etc dosent rly work but il let you know how it works out

Comment: Hi i've looked at it but im having problem with the "find all possible combinations" could you help me out some more?
http://ideone.com/t2Zvc0
The new code checks for the sum and i've changed from a list to a int array so that it adapt better to the code.